# Проблема с установкой Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Переустанавливаю винду. Все происходит нормально до первой перезагрузки во время установки. После перезагрузки установка не продолжается, а выкидывает обратно на начальную страницу установки

Comment: мб флешку нужно вытащить чтоб с нее не шла загрузка)